# Change highlight color of horizontal split statusline in vim

Tags: vim

I am using the solarized color scheme for Vim.  When I open a vim session with two windows horizontally split, the horizontal split is almost invisible.  On the other hand, vertical splits between windows are clearly visible

Here is a picture using the dark solarized theme on cygwin.  You can see a white vertical line dividing the sidebar from the other two windows.  You can also see a blank area (top window) and an area with text (bottom window).  **The problem is that there is effectively no visible divider between the top and bottom window. I would like this divider to be the same color as the vertical divider.**

(Please note this same issue occurs with any colorscheme and when using a terminal on Ubuntu as well.  Basically, no matter where I use vim the horizontal splits are not highlighted different to the background.)

[image]

Below are what I **think** are the relevant lines of solarized.vim (assuming statusline is what I want to configure).  I'm just not sure how to modify them.

```
exe "hi! StatusLine"     .s:fmt_none   .s:fg_base1  .s:bg_base02 .s:fmt_revbb
exe "hi! StatusLineNC"   .s:fmt_none   .s:fg_base00 .s:bg_base02 .s:fmt_revbb
exe "hi! Visual"         .s:fmt_none   .s:fg_base01 .s:bg_base03 .s:fmt_revbb
exe "hi! Directory"      .s:fmt_none   .s:fg_blue   .s:bg_none
exe "hi! ErrorMsg"       .s:fmt_revr   .s:fg_red    .s:bg_none
exe "hi! IncSearch"      .s:fmt_stnd   .s:fg_orange .s:bg_none
exe "hi! Search"         .s:fmt_revr   .s:fg_yellow .s:bg_none
exe "hi! MoreMsg"        .s:fmt_none   .s:fg_blue   .s:bg_none
exe "hi! ModeMsg"        .s:fmt_none   .s:fg_blue   .s:bg_none
exe "hi! LineNr"         .s:fmt_none   .s:fg_base01 .s:bg_base02
exe "hi! Question"       .s:fmt_bold   .s:fg_cyan   .s:bg_none
if ( has("gui_running") || &t_Co > 8 )
    exe "hi! VertSplit"  .s:fmt_none   .s:fg_base00 .s:bg_base00
else
    exe "hi! VertSplit"  .s:fmt_revbb  .s:fg_base00 .s:bg_base02
endif
```

EDIT: I attempted to use the commands suggested by Steve and it appears my problem is somehow much deeper.  I set the following variables but it only colored the separators around the sidebar.  Still nothing changed about the horizontal split.  Anyone know what is going on here?

```
exe "hi! StatusLine"     .s:fmt_none   .s:fg_red  .s:bg_red .s:fmt_revbb
exe "hi! StatusLineNC"   .s:fmt_none   .s:fg_red    .s:bg_red
exe "hi! VertSplit"  .s:fmt_revbb  .s:fg_red .s:bg_red
```

[image]

EDIT2: I pulled apart my .vimrc file and isolated the problem to these lines.  Once these lines are commented out the horizontal splits are styled just like the vertical ones by default....Oops!

```
set statusline=                                        " Override default
set statusline+=%2*\ %f\ %m\ %r%*                      " Show filename/path
set statusline+=%3*%=%*                                " Set right-side status info after this line
set statusline+=%4*%l/%L:%v%*                          " Set <line number>/<total lines>:<column>
set statusline+=%5*\ %*                                " Set ending space
```

Comment: I don't know have the variables are defined but my guess is you want something like `exe "hi! StatusLine"     .s:fmt_none   .s:fg_base02  .s:bg_base02 .s:fmt_revbb` Where the fg and background have the same base

Comment: @FDinoff Unfortunately, that did not seem to do anything.

Comment: I clearly don't know what I'm doing because even `exe "hi! StatusLine"     .s:fmt_none   .s:fg_green  .s:bg_green .s:fmt_revbb` doesn't change anything.

Comment: You want the VertSplit color group not the StatusLine one.

Comment: @FDinoff But doesn't the VertSplit affect the vertical line?  I want to change the color of the horizontal line.  Either way, happy to try it.  What should I change VertSplit too?

Comment: I must be confused about which part you are trying to change. But yeah I guess the one you want is StatusLine. hmmm.

Comment: Look for GUI & CSApprox hexadecimal palettes in the Solarized.vim. Mine is set to #657b83 which is visible on the Dark backround and from what I can see that's the color the Vertsplit is set to. Try setting it to one of the other colors or changing the color number

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually the Horizontal Split is  StatusLineNC

Setting it to

```
exe "hi! StatusLineNC"   .s:fmt_none   .s:fg_red .s:bg_base02 .s:fmt_revbb
```

And the Vsplit line to

```
   exe "hi! VertSplit"  .s:fmt_none   .s:fg_red .s:bg_red
```

Makes it look like the following. Not entirely visible but play with the colors.

[image]

EDIT: Using https://github.com/Rykka/colorv.vim/ to show the colors in line made it easier to see whch color was what.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix my problem, but it revealed that my problem is somewhere else.  I will pull apart my vim configuration and try adding things back slowly to see if I can isolate the problem.

Comment: I found the problem was related to some statusline formatting I had in my .vimrc.  I gave your answer credit since it is technically the correct answer to the question and it gave me the insight I needed to solve my problem.  Bonus points if you can tell me how to style the statusline without ruining the colors ;)

Comment: Don't know much about status lines but if you post the one that was causing problems it would be fun to try :)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding how to style the statusline without ruining the colors, the '%[num]*' sequences in your statusline is making it switch from the StatusLine highlight to the User[num] highlight.  If you remove those (or define the relevant highlights) you can use the customized statusbar without breaking highlighting.

From :help 'statusline'

```
 * -  Set highlight group to User{N}, where {N} is taken from the
      minwid field, e.g. %1*.  Restore normal highlight with %* or %0*.
      The difference between User{N} and StatusLine  will be applied
      to StatusLineNC for the statusline of non-current windows.
      The number N must be between 1 and 9.  See |hl-User1..9|
```